# How to convert dictionary with pandas types to json serialzable

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I'm having a python dictionary with many nested values which some of them are for example: `int64`, `timestamp` or other `pandas` types which are not json serializable.  (the format of the dictionary is not fixed.)

Do anybody aware of some function for converting python dict with pandas types to python types recursively?

Thanks

Comment: Sharing an example might help

Comment: @AlexandreB.: imagine simple dictionary with key and value in which each value you can have another dictionary, and in some nesting you have pandas datatypes, there is no specified format, I need generic algorithm for traversal  on each kind of python dictionary